# configure PHP project build in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops

I have a php Laravel instance uploaded to VSO project which is based on GIT Repository system.

The project was edited using normal text editor and thus there is no .sln file or anything and I'm trying to setup the build manually by adding a build definition then adding build steps.

The problem is there is only build steps for npm install and gulp but it seems like there is no php composer build step i added my .bat script but it responded that php command is not available.

The VSO websites says that it supports php but it seems that it doesn't or am i missing something

I know it's possible to install the required packages before pushing the code but in this situation it's required to use composer and npm after pushing the code to VSO.

Comment: Check the answer in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390181/best-practice-for-automating-php-project-builds-using-visual-studio-ultimate-onl

Comment: Also, check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/build-your-app-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [official documentation](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/vstsextend/PHP/) doesn't provide enough information about the build process and misses integration with Composer for example.

I wrote quite a long article about doing this with the built-in agent in VSTS - https://hajekj.net/2016/10/30/creating-a-build-agent-and-definition-for-php-in-vsts/

Alternatively, you could build your code in Docker container which might be much more convenient than running your own build agent - you can find more information about VSTS's Docker integration here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/languages/docker?view=vsts&tabs=yaml.

Aditionally, if you are targeting App Service with the deployment, custom deployment script might be sufficient for you - you can read more about it on my blog again: https://hajekj.net/2017/04/20/deploying-php-web-applications-to-azure-app-service/

I might write a new article about this in future detailing the PHP build steps.